# Reassignment of static items inside of a function body

Tags: rust, static

Imagine we have the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let _ = get_static_ref();
    }
}

struct SomeStruct {
    value: usize
}

fn get_static_ref() -> &'static SomeStruct {
    static MY_STRUCT: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { value: 1 };
    &MY_STRUCT
}
```

Does the `MY_STRUCT` gets reassigned on every `get_static_ref` call, or does the compiler just remove this assignment from function body?
Because if it gets reassigned, then it kind of breaks the rule, that non-mut static items are immutable, so it follows that those reassignments shouldn't happen, but that's just my guess.

I was unable to find an explicit explanation for this situation in Rust docs.

Comment: No it assigns once, you can test the behavior via this code : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a2af6b4fbc4f24e8f41b8175112f2bd

Comment: One way to think about it is that the `=` token in `get_static_ref()` doesn't denote _assignment_, but _initialization_. Since `MY_STRUCT` is static, the initialization is only performed once.

Comment: Oh, if you think about it this way, it makes sense now, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [generated code](https://godbolt.org/z/46qdMW3aW), you will see that `MyStruct` is only created once (at compile time) and that the function simply returns the existing instance:

```
example::get_static_ref:
        lea     rax, [rip + example::get_static_ref::MY_STRUCT]
        ret

example::get_static_ref::MY_STRUCT:
        .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following excerpts from [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html) may explain the static MY_STRUCT will be evaluated once at compile time.

- The static initializer is a constant expression evaluated at compile time.
- A static item is similar to a constant, except that it represents a precise memory location in the program. All references to the static refer to the same memory location.

Answer (score 2):

No. As for machine code, there is no difference between:

```rust
static MY_STRUCT: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { value: 1 };
fn get_static_ref() -> &'static SomeStruct {
    &MY_STRUCT
}
```

And

```rust
fn get_static_ref() -> &'static SomeStruct {
    static MY_STRUCT: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { value: 1 };
    &MY_STRUCT
}
```

Declaration of static inside function body just limits scope of the name.